# Accesing a variable from an object oriented function in python

Tags: python, list, variables, discord.py

```
import discord
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
client = discord.Client()
class gamecheck:
    def __init__(self, name):
        if name == "leicester":
            source = requests.get("https://www.11v11.com/teams/arsenal/tab/opposingTeams/opposition/Leicester%20City/")
        elif name == "manutd":
            source = requests.get("https://www.11v11.com/teams/arsenal/tab/opposingTeams/opposition/Manchester%20United/")


        soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')
        games = soup.find_all(class_="result-status")
        allgames = []

        for game in games:
            allgames.append(game.text)
        last5 = allgames[-5:]
        
oqr = gamecheck("leicester")
utd = gamecheck("manutd")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('!history leicester'):
        await message.channel.send("Our last 5 games with this club:")
        await message.channel.send(**last5**)
    elif message.content.startswith('!history manutd'):
        await message.channel.send("Our last 5 games with this club:")
        await message.channel.send(utd)

client.run("token")
```

This the full code but what I'm more interested in is

```
last5 = allgames[-5:]
```

I want to somehow use this variable in this line of code later on

```
if message.content.startswith('!history leicester'):
        await message.channel.send("Our last 5 games with this club:")
        await message.channel.send(last5)
```

but it wont recognize the variable. Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: First of all please refresh your token so no one can use it.

Comment: Which version of `last5` do you want? You have two instances: `oqr` and `utd`. Each of those could be made to contain a `last5`

Comment: oqr in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `__init__` method should end with this:

```py
        for game in games:
            allgames.append(game.text)
        self.last5 = allgames[-5:]
```

And then you can use:

```py
await message.channel.send(oqr.last5)
```

Comment: yup this works fine. Thank you a lot. I can mark it as the answer in 6 minutes!